# Pandas expanding window with min_periods

Tags: pandas, window

I want to compute expanding window statistics, but with a minimum number of periods of 3, rather than 1. That is, I want it start computing the statistic after the window of 3 values, and then include all values up until that point:

```
value     expanding_min
------------------------
 6          NaN
 5          NaN
 2          NaN
 3          2
 1          1
```

however, using

```
df['expanding_min']= df.groupby(groupby)['value'].transform(lambda x: pd.rolling_min(x, window=len(x), min_periods=3))
```

or

```
df['expanding_min']= df.groupby(groupby)['value'].transform(lambda x: pd.expanding_min(x, min_periods=3))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: min_periods (3) must be <= window (1)
```

Comment: did the solution posted below work?

Comment: my description was a little over-simplified. I've edited it above. But basically I want to write this to a new column in the dataframe. I don't think I can use pd.expanding_min because I get the error 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'type'

Comment: And curiously, if I put min_periods=5 in the code above (instead of 3), then I get
ValueError: Invalid min_periods size 5 greater than window 3

Or if I put 15, I get 
ValueError: Invalid min_periods size 15 greater than window 8

Comment: Does this mean the 'window' parameter has to be greater than the 'min_periods' parameter? I am not sure I understand correctly the logic here. If I have window=10, I will not get any value before reaching the 10th value. In that case what is the point to have a min_periods = 5 for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, changing from value to df.value:

```
pd.expanding_min(df.value, min_periods=3)
```

or

```
pd.rolling_min(df.value, window=len(df.value), min_periods=3)
```

both output:

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2     2
3     2
4     1
dtype: float64
```

Perhaps your window is being set by some other 'value' whose length is 1? This is why pandas is giving the error message